# Remove all non-ascii characters between "<TYPE>GRAPHIC" and "</TEXT>"

Tags: python, regex, ascii

I have a txt file directed downloaded from html whose contents like below.

```
<TYPE>GRAPHIC
<TEXT>
.....
Example of omitted part: M%$2G]\U?HQM7L^!5K*'5E/1@0?IQ5\S^0/\ G$O\IORU\W:1YV\MKK(UK1# (I guess are some kind of non-Ascii characters)
.....
</TEXT>
```

I want to remove all contents between `<TYPE>GRAPHIC` and `</TEXT>` and tried `re.sub('<TYPE>GRAPHIC(.*)</TEXT>', '', reader)` but doesn't work.

Comment: You probably need to add the singleline mode and a lazy quantifier, like so: `re.sub('<TYPE>GRAPHIC(.*?)</TEXT>', '', reader, flags = re.S)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this:

```
re.sub("(?!<TYPE>GRAPHIC)\n(?:.|\n)+(?=<\/TEXT>)", "", text)
'<TYPE>GRAPHIC</TEXT>\n'
```

There are some complex regex patterns here, if you curious about what they are, here [references for lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Hi I use this code to read txt file and try your code, but it doesn't work and saying "Memory Error". with open(filename, 'r') as file: text = file.read()   result = re.sub("(?!<TYPE>GRAPHIC)\n(?:.|\n)+(?=<\/TEXT>)", "", text)

Comment: How big is your text file? It's kind of odd.

Comment: Please: don't - the expression `(?:.|\n)+` is a nightmare - use a proper modifier (e.g. the singleline `re.S`) instead.

Comment: @metoikos the text file is of size 111,000 KB

Answer (score 1):

**Honestly, I think this is a legit question and it's probably been asked before, but re.sub behaves really oddly and takes a lot of getting used to and most answers really don't explain it. The fact that it will often ignore capture groups is especially confusing so I don't see why you were '-1'ed**

**Anyway, these two solutions should work:**

**1.**

```
>>> import re

>>> reader = '''<TYPE>GRAPHIC
    <TEXT>
    .....
    Example of omitted part: M%$2G]\U?HQM7L^!5K*'5E/1@0?IQ5\S^0/\ 
    G$O\IORU\W:1YV\MKK(UK1# 
    (I guess are some kind of non-Ascii characters)
    .....
    </TEXT>''' 

>>> re.sub("(?<=<TYPE>GRAPHIC)[\S\s]+(?=</TEXT>)", "", reader)
'<TYPE>GRAPHIC</TEXT>'
```

- **With `(?<=<TYPE>GRAPHIC)` I'm saying that what is ultimately captured must be preceded by `<TYPE>GRAPHIC`. By doing this, I'm also simultaneously saying don't act on/capture/remove `(?<=<TYPE>GRAPHIC)` itself**
- **With `[\S\s]+` I'm saying make this capture greedy and query to capture all text**
- **With `(?=</TEXT>)` I'm saying that the captured text must be followed by `</TEXT>` to be captured, but `</TEXT>` will not ultimately be removed in the re.sub string result, because this is simultaneously telling re.sub not to actually capture/act upon/remove `</TEXT>`**

.

**2.**

```
>>> import re

>>> reader = '''<TYPE>GRAPHIC
    <TEXT>
    .....
    Example of omitted part: M%$2G]\U?HQM7L^!5K*'5E/1@0?IQ5\S^0/\ 
    G$O\IORU\W:1YV\MKK(UK1# 
    (I guess are some kind of non-Ascii characters)
    .....
    </TEXT>'''


>>> parsed = re.sub(r'(<TYPE>GRAPHIC)[\S\s]+(</TEXT>)', r'\1\n\n\2', reader)
>>> print(parsed)
<TYPE>GRAPHIC

</TEXT>
```

- **With `re.sub` the "r" preceding the regex means that the engine will process it in "raw string" mode**
- **By doing that I can open the regex up to printing specific captured groups**
- **The extra caveat is that re.sub in this way usually works conversely (really inversely) to what you'd expect for what you're trying to do which is eliminate text**
- **By supplying the argument `r'\1\n\n\2'` I'm telling it keep/print my Captured Group 1 (via the `\1`), place to newline characters between and keep/print my Captured Group 2 (via the `\2`), everything else doesn't get returned and is ignored.**